# SSH VPN tunneling

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel

I am testing some basics of SSH VPNs on Layer 2 like this:

```
ssh -w 1:1 -o Tunnel=ethernet hostname
```

That works fine, but is there a way to tunnel multiple VLANs over such a SSH Tunnel? I know i could set up a tunnel on each VLAN i want to transport. What i really want to try is forwarding a VLAN Trunk to another machine. Is this possible? Any considerations?